# MySQL FIFO AVG purchase price only in stock SKU

Tags: mysql, average, fifo

Say I have purchase and sales data for some SKUs:

```
po_id | sku | purchase_date    | price | qty
----------------------------------------------
    1 | 123 | 2017-01-01 12:25 | 20.15 |   5
    2 | 123 | 2017-05-01 15:45 | 17.50 |   3
    3 | 123 | 2017-05-02 12:00 | 15.00 |   1
    4 | 456 | 2013-06-10 16:00 | 60.00 |   7
```

and

```
sale_id | sku | sale_date        | price | qty
------------------------------------------------
      1 | 123 | 2017-01-15 11:00 | 30.00 |   1
      2 | 123 | 2017-01-20 14:00 | 28.00 |   3
      3 | 123 | 2017-05-10 15:00 | 25.00 |   2
      4 | 456 | 2017-06-11 12:00 | 80.00 |   1
```

How can I find the average purchase price of in stock SKUs via SQL, assuming they are sold in the order they were purchased? E.g, the avg purchase price (using FIFO) for SKU 123 is:

We have **6 solds** for SKU 123 => with 5 purchased at 20.15, 1 purchased at 17.50 and 2 left unsold at 17.50)

Available in stock SKU 123 we have now:

```
po_id | sku | purchase_date    | price | qty
----------------------------------------------
    2 | 123 | 2017-05-01 15:45 | 17.50 |   2
    3 | 123 | 2017-05-02 12:00 | 15.00 |   1
```

Then the avg purchase price for SKU 123 is:

```
(17.50*2 + 15*1) / 3 = 16,66
```

How can I calculate this in MySQL?

Comment: Im having problems doing the cumulative calculation but this is a start. http://rextester.com/AAQ17258

Comment: Thanks for your start point!